# git stash doesn't stash changes properly

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I'm running git windows - `git version 2.16.0.windows.2`. Whenever I run `git stash` on any of my repos, git will respond with usual confirmation:

`Saved working directory and index state WIP on branch_name: last_commit`

After that, I run `git status -uno` and I'll still see the staged and unstaged changes as if I've not run the `git stash` command.

`git stash show 0` will return the list of stashed files, as the same output from the `git status -uno` command.

From here, running `git stash` again will remove the staged and unstaged changes from the repo. `git status -uno` also confirms with the "nothing to commit" message.

Running `git stash show 0` now shows no output (an empty stash?), and `git stash show 1` returns the list of stashed items.

When I want to unstash the changes, I'll need to run `git stash pop` twice to get to correct stash reference. First pop will return "Already up to date!" and the second pop will unstash my changes.

Questions:

- why is this happening?
- how do I fix this?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. I have seen similar recent questions that suggest that the Windows versions of Git 2.16 and/or 2.17 have such a bug, and that it's not present in earlier versions. Check for updates that fix it, or try going to an earlier version.

Comment: @torek that's that probably what happened, newer versions didn't have this issue.